# How can I get Azure Devops API to return the clauses of a query?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I'd like to get use the Azure DevOps API to get a specific query and modify it. My plan was to get the Get Query API, and add a new clause. However when I try to do this using the Azure DevOps C# SDK, I get null clauses. There is a read-only dictionary with a "wiql" url value, and when I load that up I see the results, not the query.

Is there a way for me to see the specific clauses in a query?

in C#, my code is specifically:

```
WorkItemTrackingHttpClient workItemTrackingClient = connection.GetClient<WorkItemTrackingHttpClient>();
var query = await workItemTrackingClient.GetQueryAsync(c_projectName, "<queryIdGuid>");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get wiql, you have to use `expand` parameter. Example:

```
QueryHierarchyItem query = workItemTrackingClient.GetQueryAsync(c_projectName, queryPath, QueryExpand.Wiql).Result;
```

The base rest API: [Queries - Get (QueryExpand)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/queries/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1#queryexpand)

Comment: thank you, this is awesome.